# How to efficiently draw a Core Image with a Filter into an NSView?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, core-image, imagefilter

I am applying a perspective [Core Image filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html) to transform and draw a [CIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage) into a custom `NSView` and it seems slower than I expected (e.g, I drag a slider that alters the perspective transformation and the drawing lags behind the slider value). Here is my custom `drawRect` method where `self.mySourceImage` is a `CIImage`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    if (self.perspectiveFilter == nil)
        self.perspectiveFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPerspectiveTransform"];

    [self.perspectiveFilter setValue:self.mySourceImage 
                            forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [self.perspectiveFilter setValue: [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0] 
                            forKey:@"inputBottomLeft"];
    // ... set other vector parameters based on slider value

    CIImage *outputImage = [self.perspectiveFilter outputImage];

    [outputImage drawInRect:dstrect 
                   fromRect:srcRect 
                  operation:NSCompositingOperationSourceOver 
                   fraction:0.8];
}
```

Here is an example output:

[image]

My experience with image filters tells me that this should be much faster. Is there some "best practice" that I am missing to speed this up?

- Note that I only create the filter once (stored as a property).
- I did make sure the view has a `CALayer` for a backing store. Should I be adding the filter to a `CALayer` somehow?
- Note that I never create a `CIContext` -- I assume there is an implicit context used by `NSView`? Should I create a `CIContext` and render to an image and draw the image?

Comment: While I code with Swift and iOS, it seems like your issue is with *how* you are drawing. (1) Don't use `draw(rect:)` in an `NSView`, code to use a `GLKView` instead. (2) As you've already implied, a `GLKView` *does* use a `CIContext`. (3) 'CALayer` shouldn't be a concern. Again, using Swift, and a `GLKView` (pretty much like a `UIImageView`) inside a `UIView` I have quite a few "near real-time" filters that a user uses `UISlliders` to alter. I could provide (iOS) code if needed.

Comment: @dfd I suppose I would use an `NSOpenGLView` in AppKit (as opposed to a `GLKView` in UIKit). How does `CIContext` work with `NSOpenGLContext` (or  `EAGLContext` in UIKit)? Seeing code is always good :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I use a `GLKView` in `UIKit`:

I prefer subclassing `GLKView` to allow for a few things:

- initializing from code
- overriding `draw(rect:)` for the `UIImageView` equivalence of `contentMode` (aspect fit in particular)
- when using `scaleAspectFit`, creating a "clear color" for the background color to match the surrounding superviews

That said, here's what I have:

```
import GLKit

class ImageView: GLKView {
    var renderContext: CIContext
    var rgb:(Int?,Int?,Int?)!
    var myClearColor:UIColor!
    var clearColor: UIColor! {
        didSet {
            myClearColor = clearColor
        }
    }
    var image: CIImage! {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    var uiImage:UIImage? {
        get {
            let final = renderContext.createCGImage(self.image, from: self.image.extent)
            return UIImage(cgImage: final!)
        }
    }
    init() {
        let eaglContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        renderContext = CIContext(eaglContext: eaglContext!)
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        context = eaglContext!
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect, context: EAGLContext) {
        renderContext = CIContext(eaglContext: context)
        super.init(frame: frame, context: context)
        enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let eaglContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        renderContext = CIContext(eaglContext: eaglContext!)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        context = eaglContext!
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let image = image {
            let imageSize = image.extent.size
            var drawFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(drawableWidth), height: CGFloat(drawableHeight))
            let imageAR = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
            let viewAR = drawFrame.width / drawFrame.height
            if imageAR > viewAR {
                drawFrame.origin.y += (drawFrame.height - drawFrame.width / imageAR) / 2.0
                drawFrame.size.height = drawFrame.width / imageAR
            } else {
                drawFrame.origin.x += (drawFrame.width - drawFrame.height * imageAR) / 2.0
                drawFrame.size.width = drawFrame.height * imageAR
            }
            rgb = myClearColor.rgb()
            glClearColor(Float(rgb.0!)/256.0, Float(rgb.1!)/256.0, Float(rgb.2!)/256.0, 0.0);
            glClear(0x00004000)
            // set the blend mode to "source over" so that CI will use that
            glEnable(0x0BE2);
            glBlendFunc(1, 0x0303);
            renderContext.draw(image, in: drawFrame, from: image.extent)
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- The *vast* majority of this was taken from something written a few years back (in Swift 2 I think) from [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/core-image-intro/) with the associated [GitHub](https://github.com/objcio/issue-21-core-image-explorer) project. In particular, check out their [GLKView subclass](https://github.com/objcio/issue-21-core-image-explorer/blob/master/Core%20Image%20Explorer/FilteredImageView.swift) that has code for `scaleAspectFill` and other content modes.
- Note the usage of a single `CIContext` called `renderContext`. I use it to create a `UIImage` when needed (in iOS you "share" a UIImage).
- I use a `didSet` with the `image` property to automatically call `setNeedsDisplay` when the image changes. (I also call this explicitly when an iOS device changes orientation.) I do not know the macOS equivalent of this call.

I hope this gives you a good start for using OpenGL in macOS. If it's anything like `UIKit`, trying to put a `CIImage` in an `NSView` doesn't involve the GPU, which is a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll look it over. It looks like `NSOpenGLView` has a `NSOpenGLContext` from which you can get a `CGLContextObj` from which you can create a `CIContext`. Using `CIImage` in an does involve the GPU, but it needlessly copies stuff back and forth between the CPU and GPU ... I think that's where the inefficiency lies. If this is what I need to do to use `CIImage` efficiently I could just skip it and use OpenGL directly -- `CIImage` stuff seems seems like a waste if I have to use OpenGL anyway.